# what is the correct way to create a Vuetfiy grid?

Tags: vue.js, responsive-design, vuetify.js

The [Vuetify docs](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/#nested-grid) have lots of examples of how to use their grid layout support, e.g. a nested grid

```
  <v-container class="grey lighten-5">
    <v-row>
      <v-col sm="9">
        Row 1, Col 1
        <v-row>
          <v-col
            cols="8"
            sm="6"
          >
          Row 2, Col 1
          </v-col>
          <v-col
            cols="4"
            sm="6"
          >
          Row 2, Col 2
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </v-container>
```

But it's not clear to me what the requirements are for how these elements should be used. For example:

- Is `<v-container>` required?
- Does `<v-row>` in the parent grid have to be a *direct* child of `<v-container>`

Answer (score 1):

```
Is `<v-container`> required?
```

No it's not required

> Does  in the parent grid have to be a direct child of

If you use the `v-container` and you want to use grid system, then yes.

Although, it's not necessary to use `v-container`, just starting with `v-row` and then using `v-col` you can achieve anything. Of course v-row and v-col have many attributes that can help.

Check this playground https://v2.vuetifyjs.com/en/components/grids/
After the `API` section there is one called `PLAYGROUND`

This PLAYGROUND helped me to understand how grid works.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain what difference does using `v-container` make?

Comment: `v-container` provides the ability to center and horizontally pad your site's contents. You can also use the fluid prop to fully extend the container across all viewport and device sizes.